# Как вытащить( ссылку )точнее селектор из location.href средствами рhpQuery?

Tags: javascript, yii2, phpquery

Как вытащить ссылку, а точнее селектор из **location.href** средствами **рhpQuery**?

Так не хочет:

```
$pqLink = pq($link); //pq делает объект phpQuery
$href = $pqLink->attr('href');
```